# Xcode fonts disappeared, how to fix?

Tags: xcode, fonts

My Xcode fonts went missing.

When i try to edit anything via storyboard i can't choose any other font than system. The custom fonts section is not available, it shows "custom (none installed).

I tried restart, build clean but still nothing. 
Other text editors like word can access my fonts properly but for now Xcode somehow isn't. What might be the problem and how to fix it?

I just tried to edit some older phone application and it allows me to use custom fonts, but when i'm editing my new apple watch then this problem appears?
Or does apple take out custom fonts capability on new Xcode build, and we cant use any custom font anymore in apple watch apps?